# Installing Non-Repository Program in Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, image-processing

I'd like to install the image editing CLI program [NConvert](https://www.xnview.com/en/nconvert/) to WSL, but I'm not sure if this is possible, since NConvert isn't in any repository. There is a procedure I could implement to attempt an installation, but I'm cautious, as I don't want to [break anything](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/).

I was considering installing it with the following steps:

`ubuntu@DESKTOP-NAC9118:~$ wget http://download.xnview.com/NConvert-linux64.tgz`

`ubuntu@DESKTOP-NAC9118:~$ tar xvzf NConvert-linux64.tgz`

`ubuntu@DESKTOP-NAC9118:~$ cd NConvert`

`ubuntu@DESKTOP-NAC9118:~/NConvert$`

This last step has me confused, as I'm not sure if I should copy the NConvert executable to `C:\Users\dmm\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\usr\bin\` or someplace else. I would also need to open the bin folder in root and change the permissions of NConvert with chmod -R 755.

EDIT: I solved the problem. The mistake I was making was assuming there was no `/usr/bin` folder into which to copy nconvert, because when I ran `ls` at the Ubuntu prompt it didn't show me the FHS, but just some files. I needed to run `ls /` and then I was able to see the FHS. I copied nconvert into `/usr/bin` and did chmod and it works fine now. – user8547

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advise you NOT to copy the executable to that directory.
You can use sudo to copy it to /usr/local/bin/.
It would be better to add the directory of the executable
to your PATH in ~/.bash_profile or ~/.profile.

Comment: The mistake I was making was assuming there was no `/usr/bin` folder into which to copy nconvert, because when I ran `ls` at the Ubuntu prompt it didn't show me the FHS, but just some files. I needed to run `ls /` and then I was able to see the FHS. I copied nconvert into `/usr/bin` and did chmod and it works fine now.